# Join two dataframes in R which only share some similar rows R

Tags: r, if-statement, join, merge

I have the following two similar dataframes:

```
d1<-data.frame(TNR=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),EP=c(0,3,1,2,NA,NA,NA))
d2<-data.frame(TNR=c("E",1,3,5,100), EP=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

In d2 the vector "EP" is empty and i want to fill it with the data from d1$EP, where the vectors TNR overlap with each other. Where they don't overlap I want to keep d2 and not d1.

The result should look something like that:

```
d3<-data.frame(TNR=c("E",1,3,5,100),EP=c(NA,0,1,NA,NA))
```

I tried the following approach with ifelse and %in%:

```
d3<-data.frame(TNR=ifelse(test=d1$TNR %in% d2$TNR, yes=d2$EP, no=NA),
               EP=ifelse(test=d1$TNR %in% d2$TNR, yes=d1$EP, no="")) 
#remove rows where TNR is NA

d4=d3[!is.na(d1$baumnummer),]
```

However, the result is that EP is inserted in the wrong order and it seems to delete more rows than I anticipated because the resulting dataframe is shorter than d2

Comment: Please provide proper reproducible examples

Comment: I didn't? Aren't d1<-data.frame(TNR=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),EP=c(0,3,1,2,,,)) and d2<-data.frame(TNR=c(E,1,3,5,100), EP=c(,,,,)) reproducible examples?

Comment: It throws an error: `Error in c(0, 3, 1, 2, , , ) : argument 5 is empty`

Comment: Ah okay, sorry I'll fix that, give me a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that OK?

```r
d2$EP <- d1[match(x = d2$TNR, table = d1$TNR), ]$EP
```

Comment: Yes, this is the result I wish for. I'm not really good at R, could you explain me what I'm looking at, so I understand what I'm copy&pasting? Thanks!

Comment: From help: `match returns a vector of the positions of (first) matches of its first argument in its second.` So with this we have first positions of values from d2$TNR in column d1$TNR. With those positions we call specific values from `d1` table, from `EP` column.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
> d1 <- data.frame(TNR=as.character(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)),EP=c(0,3,1,2,NA,NA,NA))
> d2 <- data.frame(TNR=c('E',1,3,5,100))
> d3 <- merge(d1, d2, by = 'TNR', all = TRUE)
> d3
  TNR EP
1   1  0
2 100 NA
3   2  3
4   3  1
5   4  2
6   5 NA
7   6 NA
8   7 NA
9   E NA
```

To sort you can use `order()`.
There are alternatives to base merge perhaps with slightly different behavior: data.table::merge, dplyr:join_*

Comment: No because it doesn't remove the rows from d1, that are not appearing in d2. But it's close!

Comment: Try replacing `all = TRUE` with `all.y = TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it with `dplyr`. First convert the TNR column to character, then `right_join` the two dataframes. Finally, we can use `coalesce` to merge the `EP` column, eliminating NAs.

```
library(dplyr)

d1 %>%
    mutate(TNR = as.character(TNR)) %>%
    right_join(d2, by = "TNR") %>%
    mutate(EP = coalesce(EP.x, EP.y), .keep = 'unused')

  TNR EP
1   1  0
2   3  1
3   5 NA
4   E NA
5 100 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

We might use {powerjoin}

```r
library(powerjoin)
library(dplyr)

power_left_join(
  d2, 
  mutate(d1, TNR = as.character(TNR)), 
  by = "TNR", 
  conflict = coalesce_yx
)
#>   TNR EP
#> 1   E NA
#> 2   1  0
#> 3   3  1
#> 4   5 NA
#> 5 100 NA
```